# Unable to determine cause of DB crash

Tags: orientdb

I have hosted an instance of OreintDB on azure VM. This instance crashes or stops on its own after sometime. And I am unable to find the reason for that.

To find the reason I have enabled logs. But to no avail. The logs printed are insufficient to point to any problem. Following the is the orient-server-log.properties

```
    # Specify the handlers to create in the root logger
    # (all loggers are children of the root logger)
    # The following creates two handlers
    handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler

    # Set the default logging level for the root logger
    .level = INFO
    com.orientechnologies.level = INFO
    com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.level = INFO

    # Set the default logging level for new ConsoleHandler instances
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
    # Set the default formatter for new ConsoleHandler instances
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.orientechnologies.common.log.OAnsiLogFormatter

    # Set the default logging level for new FileHandler instances
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
    # Naming style for the output file
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=../log/orient-server.log
    # Set the default formatter for new FileHandler instances
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogFormatter
    # Limiting size of output file in bytes:
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000
    # Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an
    # integer to the base file name:
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10
```

Following is the contents of one of the log file generated named **orient-server.log.0**:

```
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:06:517 INFO  Loading configuration from: /opt/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:06:917 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.13 (build 2.2.x@r90d7caa1e4af3fad86594e592c64dc1202558ab1; 2016-11-15 12:04:05+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:06:921 INFO  Databases directory: /opt/orientdb/databases [OServer]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:010 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=4,428MB (heap=491MB direct=524,288MB os=6,967MB) [orientechnologies]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:719 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.36, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:730 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:761 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.2.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:765 INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:766 INFO  OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:766 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:805 INFO  Installed GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:805 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:808 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:810 INFO  OrientDB Studio available at http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
XXXX-XX-XX 05:10:07:810 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.13 (build 2.2.x@r90d7caa1e4af3fad86594e592c64dc1202558ab1; 2016-11-15 12:04:05+0000).
```

Other log files have similar content.

I want some pointer of what could be the issue or some other debugging method. Crash report, DB connection reports, etc. which can help me determine the underlying problem.

I am using OrientDB **v2.2.13**

Comment: If there are no logs in OrientDB about the crash, Linux could have killed the process because of the RAM used. How much RAM do you have before starting OrientDB and what is your setting about max heap and diskcache?

Comment: @Lvca Hi. The Azure VM has 7GB of memory. And I think RAM when starting OrientDB should suffice. I haven't configured any specific settings, so disk cache & max heap should be default. The sample log states these settings I think at line 4.
INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=4,428MB (heap=491MB direct=524,288MB os=6,967MB)

Comment: Before starting OrientDB, could you please check the available RAM?

Comment: free -m returns this result

Mem: 6967(total), 1263(used), 1737(free), 73(shared), 3966(buff/cache), 5283(available)

It crashed again, so I am going to restart.

Comment: Try to set this: `-Xmx1G -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=2048`